# methods calling methods inside object

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

i would like to know if there is a name for the pattern (is a pattern?) that i use. For example, instead of use like this:

```
var MyFakeClass = function(propertie) {
 this.propertie = propertie

 this.init();
};

MyFakeClass.prototype.method = function() {
 // something here
};

var instanceOfFakeClass = new MyFakeClass('propertie');
instanceOfFakeClass.method();
```

I do as follow:

```
var MyFakeClass = {
 init: function(propertie) {
  this.propertie = propertie;
  this.method();
 },

 method: function() {
  // something here
 }
};

MyFakeClass.init('propertie');
```

So, the init method calls the method, i don't need call from the outside.

Thanks.

Comment: Within *init*, *this* will be *MyFakeClass*, you aren't creating instances. Where do you create the instances?

Comment: If you want to put a shiny name on your code, call it a *singleton*  or a *module*  or just an *object*.

Comment: @RobG No, she's not. So like Bergi says, it's **singleton** indeed.

Comment: @Leo—she's not what? Or do you mean it's not intended to create instances? In that case, ECMA-262 calls it an "[*object initialiser*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer)" or Object literal.

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to describe it and probably no single moniker that is always used for that:

1. Object literal
2. Statically declared object
3. Statically declared singleton

"Singleton" is probably a useful word here because it describes an object of which there is only intended to be one of.  There are many different possible ways to declare a singleton.  Your declaration is one such way.

"Statically declared" differentiates your second option from the first one with a constructor that is created with `new`.

Comment: ECMA-262 also calls it an [*object initialiser*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object-initializer).

Comment: @RobG - `Object Initializer` is the title of that section in the spec and the grammar defines it as an `ObjectLiteral`.  "Object Literal" is a fairly common description for a statically defined object like this in normal conversation about Javascript code.  "Literal" seems to be the word that typically distinguishes something that is declared with object definition syntax.  I haven't personally heard anyone call it an "object initializer", though certainly one can see the common sense logic in that description.   The use of the word "singleton" would help describe the design intent.

Comment: Sure, since you listed various names I was just pointing out one more. The spelling of "initialiser" was changed in ECMAScript 2015.